# Can't remove WooCommerce's image zoom

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, content-management-system

I am trying to remove the image zoom from my custom themed website which uses WooCommerce. Here is what I've tried adding in my functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_pgz_theme_support', 100 );

function remove_pgz_theme_support() {
    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
}
```

and this

```
add_action( 'wp', 'remove_pgz_theme_support', 20 );

function remove_pgz_theme_support() {
    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
}
```

I've spend some time googling but the answers always recommend trying something along the lines of the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is adding the following to your functions.php file

```
// Add WooCommerce support
function add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_woocommerce_support' );
```

Comment: Why on earth would adding theme support of woocommerce disable the image zoom? Surely this is doing more than just that

Comment: This didn;t work.

Answer (score 4):

I disable all image effects with:

```
add_action('wp', 'remove_woo_image_effects');
function remove_woo_image_effects() {

    // this should be disable the gallery slider and lightbox
    remove_theme_support('wc-product-gallery-lightbox');
    remove_theme_support('wc-product-gallery-slider');

    // this should be disable the zoom
    remove_theme_support('wc-product-gallery-zoom');
}
```

I tested it with DIVI and two from my custom themes
checked it here with [custom theme](https://dev.bcis-akademie.de/product/elo-office-schulung/)

Comment: which way you added woocommerce support?

Comment: What do you mean which way? I just added the code from my answer to functions.php

Comment: if you have a custom theme, you must declare woocommerce support. there are 2 ways to do it. which one have you done?

Comment: Check my answer.