# WooCommerce: how to disable image zoom?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce we want to disable the product image zoom on hover. I've seen multiple options to do it in the child theme, functions.php. But they all are not working.

The child theme function.php is working (has some other code in it that is working). It's also not working when I put it in the main theme function.php file.

I've tried:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_zoom_enabled', '__return_false' );
```

and

```
function remove_image_zoom_support() {
    remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-zoom' );
}
add_action( 'wp', 'remove_image_zoom_support', 100 );
```

and

```
add_filter( ‘woocommerce_single_product_zoom_options’, ‘custom_single_product_zoom_options’, 10, 3 );
function custom_single_product_zoom_options( $zoom_options ) {
// Disable zoom magnify:
$zoom_options[‘magnify’] = 0;

return $zoom_options;
}
```

Any more options?

Comment: Maybe you can find a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704326/cant-remove-woocommerces-image-zoom and here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/disable-new-gallery-and-zoom-at-single-product-pages/

Comment: In the second option, replace the 'wp' with 'after_setup_theme'. You could also try adding remove_theme_support( 'wc-product-gallery-lightbox' );

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All the given options don't work. The theme has a (hidden) builtin feature for this.
Thanks for the replies.

Comment: I didn't understand. What is this hidden feature?

Comment: In our theme there was an option in the customizer for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ([...document.querySelectorAll(".zoomImg")].length > 0) {
        [...document.querySelectorAll(".zoomImg")].map((item) => {
            //remove item from dom
            item.parentElement.removeChild(item);
        });
    }
```

This should work, I'm removing the element that triggers the zoom on hover entirely.